# algebra equation: x + 5y = 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I solved a question but I have doubt in it,

Which of the following point satisfies the equation: $x + 5y = 3$

my answer: $(-2, 1)$

Is it correct?

Comment: That answer does make that formula true, but where is the calculus? This is algebra, not calculus

Comment: Where is the list of possible answers? Usually questions that start with "which" have a list and without knowing the other choices, it is hard to say this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is right, but it is only one out of infinitely many correct solutions.
For example, consider (-7,2).

Probably you have to explain how to find all of them.

Comment: The question has the word "following" in it.I am thinking it is an MCQ.

Comment: Yes it is! I solved and got that answer!